# I'm trying to write a code for a random number > 0, but it keep spitting out 0's

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, numbers

I'm trying to write a code for a random number > 0, but it keeps spitting out 0's.

```
import random
bch = random.randint(1, 3)
bch > 0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to format your code so that it renders properly. Is that all your code? Right now it doesn't seem to have any output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

bch = random.randint(1, 3)

print 'You have been given number: ' + str(bch)
```

This will print out any random number from 1 - 3, is this the outcome your are trying to achieve? If you've declared 1 as your starting number it won't get a number any lower than that.

Also, there is no need to include the "> 0" line as it won't get any number below 1 or higher than 3.

if you want a random number from 1 to 100 you would just change the line

```
bch = random.randint(1, 3)
```

To:

```
bch = random.randint(1, 100)
```